# Apache Kafka: seek and assignment. Reliable read from beginning

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to implement basic scenario, re-read topic from beginning (at least 1 message), and I'm facing unexpected behavior.

Suppose, there are 1 partition topic holding exactly 1 million messages, 1 consumer with offset already committed somewhere at middle, no active producers.

First I've tried

```
  consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
  consumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.emptySet());
  consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(longTimeout)); //no loop to simplify
```

And that doesn't work (no messages polled). I've read that `seekToBeginning` is lazy (and that's ok), but it turns out, `seekToBeginning` doesn't impact at all, cause it need partitions to be already assigned, what will only happen with first poll. Should it be described at docs, or have I missed it?

Then I've tried

```
  consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(topic));
  consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(assignTimeout));
  consumer.seekToBeginning(Collections.emptySet());
  consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(longTimeout));//no loop to simplify
```

And turns out, it depends on `assignTimeout`. It should be enough to complete join process. That time may vary and it's not possible to rely on it.

Then I've provided `ConsumerRebalanceListener` with

```
    @Override
    public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
      consumer.seekToBeginning(partitions);
    }
```

And single `poll` left. And it finally seems to work.

So the questions are:

1. Is `seekToBeginning` right after `subscribe` useless? Should it be documented?
2. Is solution with `ConsumerRebalanceListener` reliable? Does it guarantee that no messages from middle (committed offset) would be polled before seek will apply?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For the first one**:

You've rightly mentioned this in your question that the pre-requisite for `seek()` or `seekToXXXX()` operations is that the partitions need to be assigned. This will not happen until we join a consumer group and this will happen only if we call `poll()`. So, `seek()` operation not working immediately after the `subscribe()` is the expected behaviour.

This is actually documented in Kafka's Definitive Guide, Chapter 4 Kafka Consumers, Section - Consuming Records with Specific Offsets.

**For the second question**:

Yes, using `ConsumerRebalanceListener` is reliable and is a recommended approach as per Kafka's Definitive Guide.

Here's the statement from the same chapter that confirms the same:

> There are many different ways to implement exactly-once semantics
>   ..................., but all of them will
>   need to use the ConsumerRebalance Listener and seek() to make sure
>   offsets are stored in time and that the consumer starts reading
>   messages from the correct location.

Hope this helps!